# JRebel in IntelliJ web project, 404 error

Tags: intellij-idea, web-deployment, jrebel

I have a JEE web project that I first created in Eclipse. I used the Eclipse jrebel plugin to debug, and everything works fine. Now I have migrated it to IntelliJ, and am using the JRebel plugin. The project seems to deploy fine when I run it. Breakpoints on startup code are hit. However, when I bring up the home page in my browser I get an error 'Request not understood by server. (404)'. REST calls are not working.
I have not trying to make any in-flight changes to the code, just want to get it working first.

I have looked in jrebel.log, there is nothing special there.

Comment: Check the deployment context in the run configuration, see the server logs. Make sure you open the correct URL that corresponds to the deployment context.

Comment: It is the correct URL - it works fine if run in plain debug in the IDE. These issues are only when running with JRebel Debug

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - don't use the rebel.xml files that are generated by IntelliJ, use the maven plugin instead. Add this to the maven file in your parent pom -

```
<build>
...
 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.9</version>
                    <executions>
                          <execution>
                                <id>generate-rebel-xml</id>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                      <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                          </execution>
                    </executions>
              </plugin>
...
</build>
```